# Create Datatable from excel and write back to excel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, boolean, xlsx

I have created a C# program that monitors a folder using fileSystemWatcher.Renamed where string contains "xlsx" which prevents duplicate notifications and then reads from a specified range E6:AA:10000 in excel and creates a Datatable using System.Data.OleDb.

This works perfectly and updates and or creates records via an API. My issue is I don't believe that you can write back to the excel file to flag a row as processed so when the file is updated it will process all rows again.

As it may be processing multiple files it is a bit convoluted to create an index file and if rows are deleted in one of the excel files it could break the index. I would also prefer not to query the API for each record each time it's updated to see if it exists and would prefer to only process new rows.

What techniques do you use for programs that import excel.xlsx data to know what rows are new and haven't been previously processed?

Comment: can you elaborate on this statement? : `I don't believe that you can write back to the excel file`.

Comment: You may find this link useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Using OleDb you can't write back to the xlsx file like you can with say SQL. My question was is there a way to read an xlsx file and write back to it in C#. So in essence my question was to programmers that deal with xlsx files in their programs is there a way to read and then write back so processed rows are flagged in the next load of the data. I was hoping for an answer like use [EPPLUS](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) where you can create an ExcelPackage package and set the value of a cell as you iterate through rows and then do a package.Save().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this issue using [EPPLUS](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) where I can read in all cells to a Datatable and write back to a specific row and save the excel file as below.

```
using System;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace excelReadWrite
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create Excel Package and set path
            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"D:\IDG\test2.xlsx"));
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ToDataTable(package);
        }
        public static DataTable ToDataTable(ExcelPackage package)
        {
            // Sets worksheet to first sheet found
            ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            // Iterate through first row and set Datatable columns
            foreach (var firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
            }
            // Iterate through all rows and set values
            for (var rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
            {
                var row = workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1, rowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column];
               var newRow = table.NewRow();
                foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                    newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Value;
                }
                // Set value of every row processed last column to 1
                workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column].Value = 1;
                table.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
            // Save excel file
            package.Save();
            return table;

        }

    }
}
```